# Error with makemigrations and migration command in django 1.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using django 1.7. In my models.py I created two models (A and B). I execute makemigrations command, after its successful execution I run the migration command which throws some exception in with regards model B. I made the required corrections and, run makemigrations and migration commands respectively. When migration command executes, it gives me a exception stating that Model A already exists. In both the cases the migrate command had failed so how can Model A be created. Please someone could help me with this. Let me know if some more information is required.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your stacktrace and model definitions please?

Comment: In some cases this might be cause if the first migration file is still there. Try to delete (move) newly generated files under migrations and try again.